# "Pop-ups are currently blocked" popup message in iOS Hybrid app on iPhones

Tags: lightning, mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, popup

We are facing an issue in salesforce hybrid app in iPhones only. In the app we are displaying HTML content using lightning-input-rich-text tag. But when we click on any link (Anchor tag) from the HTML, it  is showing us an error message “Pop-ups are currently blocked. To View notifications, configure your browser to show pop-ups.”.

Issue is only in iPhone’s hybrid app. In Safari browser it is working fine. In iPad also it is working fine (even in hybrid app). We also checked the iPhone’s settings and allowed the pop-ups.

Below is the sample HTML and LWC code.

Js File: richtext = `"<h2>Default <s>Value</s></h2> <a target='_blank' href='https://example.com/:f:/p/virai_sarvaiya/EsVfwAQ8aGZNoF8tVee1vj4BH2PzDDK2pLPlAaIf1wEGxQ?e=JIxwE6' style='font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; color: #0066aa;'>link</a>";`

HTML file:  `<[![lightning-formatted-rich-text][1]][1] value={richtext}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>`

[image]